# Presort Silverlight DataGrid in MVVM

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm binging `DataGrid` to `ObservableCollection` I update collection on timer and grid updates nicely which is what I want.

However, even though I can sort collection on initial population - when I append new items they go to bottom. User can sort grid and then it looks good.

I would like to "force" grid to sort by specific column when it is initialized. Can it be done in XAML or somehow in MVVM manner?

**EDIT**
Just to give more details. This is mail client main screen. I've got service that polls for data and if new mail arrived - it get's appended to collection. Sorting at this point is not desirable for couple reasons. First, this is list of `object`. Second, user may decided to sort by other column using `DataGrid`

It feels right to set grid to sort by column I initially want (Time Received) and let users sort by any column while preserving this order when new items arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] Edited the answer to correspond to the solution

You can try adding SortDescriptions by including the Collection in a collectionView. In example.

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ObservableCollection}" x:Key="Data" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="City" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Then in your ItemsSource set the following binding.

```
ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource Data}}
```

Comment: I'm Sorry. How it works in Silverlight 4 now is that you indeed wrap it in a CollectionViewSource. this can be done in XAML or your viemodel. I've tested it to make sure this will work.

`<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ObservableCollection}" x:Key="Data" >
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="City" />
   </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>`
Put the above in your resources of your page/usercontrol, and then you can set your ItemsSource
`ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test}}"`

Comment: Source={StaticResource Test} should be Source={StaticResource Data}

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your ObservableCollection in a collection view. Generally you will wrap the collection in either a CollectionViewSource, or a PagedCollectionView. The CollectionViewSource can be used declaratively in XAML, but can't be controlled from the ViewModel. You can however wrap your collection in a PagedCollectionView, and expose that from your ViewModel. This MSDN article should help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072(v=vs.95).aspx. Collection views are very powerful tools, and will help you elegantly bridge the gap between a View and a ViewModel. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort inside your ViewModel, where ever you're updating the collection from the timer sort it.  In fact when you sort the collection the view should rebind if you're binding correctly in the View/Xaml to the datacontext(the viewmodel).

Anytime you update an Observable collection in a viewmodel anything that's bound to it will be updated.

Comment: See my edit. I really do want to set grid. This will even show them visually that it is sorted by this column